# Java - Read resource with getResourceAsStream(String)

Tags: java, resources

Can someone explain why Java does not find resource if using `File.separator` in the String for search path in `getResourceAsStream(String name)`? I have this code:

```
private final String RESOURCE_PATH = File.separator + "dir" + File.separator;
private final String SAME_PATH_HARDCODED = "/dir/";

public void findResource(String fileName) {
    InputStream file1 = ThisClass.class
            .getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_PATH + fileName);  // returns null

    InputStream file2 = ThisClass.class
            .getResourceAsStream(SAME_PATH_HARDCODED + fileName);  // returns file
}
```

I have found out, that `File.separator` used Backslashes instead of Slashes. But I hoped that File.separator is more flexible. In this case, it isnt. And I want to know, why. Thanks alot.

Comment: I tried the same,but i didnt get any exception.

Comment: There is no exception because this method returns null if not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you pass `\\` separator to `getResourceAsStream()` method it interprets path to your dir in another way, added package name before dir actually.

[Class javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> ```
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>     modified_package_name/name 
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').
> ```

Your `File.separator` returns different result for unix and windows machines. If you use mack or unix in this case your code will works but in win machine fails.

[File javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar)

> public static final char separatorChar
>
> The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is
>   initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system
>   property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is
>   '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.